# Trying to lazy load android view using generics

Tags: java, android, generics

I have an application and in one of my activities I created a base activity that contains some helper methods that derived classes can use.

I have a method that lazy loads views, here is the code

```
    protected <T extends View> void loadView(T view, int id) {
    if(view == null){
        view = (T)findViewById(id);
    }
```

In my derived class I call it as such.

```
private Button btnAddAlarm
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer_list);

    loadView(btnDeleteAlarm, R.id.btnDeleteAlarm); //the view in the helper method loaded fine
    btnDeleteAlarm.setEnabled(false); //Null pointer exception!
```

the problem is that btnDeleteAlarm is null after it exits from the function, even though the reference is passed in.

I haven't touched java in a while but if I remember the basics this shouldn't happen when passing references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assigned something to btnDeleteAlarm.
In java, methods always copy their arguments, so loadView gets a copy of the reference btnDeleteAlarm and maybe changes the copy, but it wont change btnDeleteAlarm.
You could let your loadView method return the "view" and assign it in the onCreate method to btnDeleteAlarm.

Comment: I see now, I misunderstood the image I had in my head of the argument reference copying.